# selenium grid on docker sizing for maximum stability

Tags: docker, selenium, testing, amazon-ec2

We are having trouble upgrading to selenium 4.

The features and performance of selenium 4 look amazing, but we are having trouble getting our pipeline stable and consistently green.

We need some advice to help us fix some of the infrastructure issues we are seeing.

We are getting lots of `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id` errors, and they are not consistant.  We are also getting other session runtime exceptions.

We are testing our own website, which is on the internet, using selenium.  We use selenium to click on buttons and fill out forms and stuff, via chromedriver in tests written in kotlin. Running these tests on a selenium 4.1.2 grid is basically broken for us.

We have a couple hundred selenium tests.  We want them to complete as quickly as possible, so we are trying to balance our base hardware with the maximum throughput of "UI actions".

We are running our selenium 4 grid on a feature branch on our build agents, which are TeamCity build agents on c5.4xlarge instances; each build has its own grid in its own docker network. Our grid's docker images are installed on our agents at runtime as part of starting our build.

We are invoking our build via gradle and testng, eg:

```
test {
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
    useTestNG {
        suites 'src/test/resources/selenium-' + suite + '.xml'
        preserveOrder true
        threadCount 2
        parallel 'classes'
        useDefaultListeners = true
    }
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

We have tried increasing and decreasing the value of `SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT` in our docker compose file, and increasing and decreasing the number of grid nodes via the absence or presence of entries like:

```
services:

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.1.2-20220208
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"

  chrome1:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.1.2-20220208
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=1200 # 1,200 secs = 20 mins
      - START_XVFB=${START_XVFB}
    ports:
      - "59001:5900"
```

Our existing tests running under selenium 3.14x jars and selenium 3.14x grid are far far more stable than under 4.x.

What is the right hardware to run an n node selenium grid on?

What is the right balance of selenium clients pumping in commands to a grid executing them?

Why is selenium 3.x so different from 4.x?

If you worked at amazon and had 1,000 selenium tests, how would you size your selenium grid for 4.x?

I have __ testrunner threads, so I need __ grid nodes __ with __ cpus.

Any help or tips are appreciated!

Thanks!
-neil

Answer (score 1):

> Why is selenium 3.x so different from 4.x?

Selenium Grid 3.x had got performance and reliability issues starting from serving 20-30+ nodes per a single hub.

So Selenium Hub, which was monolite in selenium 3.x has been splited on multiple components:

- router
- distributor
- sessions-map
- session-queue
- event-bus

This has been done in order to improve the Selenium Grid Cluster reliability (since a single component down might bring less issues, e.g. the new sessions cannot created, but existing sessions works.).

There were also reasons to optimize jars size, cleanup some legacy code, allow a single hub to serve more nodes then earlier, etc.

But now, while Selenium Grid 4.x aimed to become more optimized, flexible and reliable it also became more complex to configure.

Just look at the full services list:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/docker-compose-v3-full-grid.yml

---

> What is the right hardware to run an n node selenium grid on?

I would say - no any specific or optimized hardware is required for web-browsers launch.

For `c5.4xlarge instance` with 16CPU and 32GB RAM it should be possible to launch at least 1 browser instance per CPU. And for critical load - 2 browsers per CPU.

So for this env I would expect ~ 16-24 parallel selenium sessions (if you'll have a single selenium hub).

---

> What is the right balance of selenium clients pumping in commands to a grid executing them?

Selenium 3.x was able to serve up-to 20-30 nodes without performance issues.

For Selenium 4.x I would expect this count increased, but I've not tested this.

Anyway, having 1 Selenium Hub per 2 Selenium Nodes as in your example, I think is overhead, but it's mandatory for docker-selenium to launch Selenium Hub even if you going to have even only one node.

---

> If you worked at amazon and had 1,000 selenium tests, how would you size your selenium grid for 4.x?

Usually we test a single test application instance, so parallelism might be limited by the test application ability to serve multiple users requests.

I've faced a cases when I able to launch 10 more parallel threads, but test app starts returning 500 errors.

For 1000 selenium tests I'll try to launch 15-20 parallel sessions and look if further increasing parallel sessions count still brings some profit.

The main point here: what is the time limit for build? 7 minutes, or 30 minutes, or 60 minutes.. Strategy aligned to this.

#### Instability Causes

I'll try to list my thouts about your sessions instability causes:

1. For Selenium 4.x it's highly recommended to set the flag `--shm-size`, and it's missed in your config example.

   From: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#--shm-size2g

   > When executing docker run for an image that contains a browser please use the flag --shm-size=2g to use the host's shared memory.
   >
   > This is a known workaround to avoid the browser crashing inside a docker container, here are the documented issues for Chrome and Firefox. The shm size of 2gb is arbitrary but known to work well, your specific use case might need a different value, it is recommended to tune this value according to your needs.
2. Having 2 Nodes per Hub might be not optimal, a single Hub is able to serve at least 20+ Nodes.
3. 1 Browser per CPU is optimal, 2 Browsers per CPU might be possible.
4. Reusing browser sessions per many tests?

   I suggest do not reuse sessions. I try do not share sessions between tests,
   and do not keep browser working > 10 minutes. I've noticed that
   reliability decreases if the browser session have already worked for
   some time. I think it's just a good practice to prevent an
   additional instability.

#### Selenium Grid Alternatives?

I still don't think that Selenium Grid is quite reliable approach for implementing Selenium Clusters.

For the last 4 years I'm using [Selenoid](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid). And this is just my own experience (I'm just a fan), this tool is simple, reliable and works like a charm.

At least several years ago it was already providing everything I've expected from Selenium Grid and what Selenium Grid trying to achieve for now.

**References**

- https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/
- https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/components/
- https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid
- https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/